# Visual Studio Code html.erb loops not indenting correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, rubocop

I dont like posting what should be a simple question, but I have spend days looking for the answer and I have uninstalled and re-installed vscode but I still have the issue. Any loop structure within a html.erb file gets un-indented.

```
<%if true%>
  <p>Something</p>
<%end%>
```

will get formatted back to

```
<%if true%>
<p>Something</p>
<%end%>
```

I have ruby-rubocop installed for the formatter and here is my settings.json

```
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons-mac",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"ruby.format": "rubocop",
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
"files.associations": {
  "html.erb": "erb"
},
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing? Certainly there is a setting that I am missing, and that this wouldn't be a feature that is unsupported.

Comment: Maybe you need an extra vs code extension to support that feature. In my case, I've installed [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vortizhe.simple-ruby-erb), and it works good enough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have that installed as well (along with the standard rails, ruby, and ruby on rails) extensions installed. I tried removing my settings that specifies rubocop as the formatter, and it still doesn't indent correctly.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you change `<%if true%>` to `<% if true %>`?

Comment: @dbugger Good question, however it doesn't effect the indentations.

Comment: Might have some conflicting extensions -- I'd be tempted to go down to nothing and add back in one-by-one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*TL;DR:* **Replace `html` with `*` on your config and it should work**.

I had the same problem as you and I gladly found a fix. At least, it worked for me.

Initially, I thought what did the trick was installing an extension called [ERB Formatter/Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aliariff.vscode-erb-beautify).

Then, I realized, just by following their install instructions, that the ERB was probably being recognized as an HTML file and not ERB. And the formatting was probably working fine. It was just not understanding it was ruby code, but rather HTML.

The extension recommends you adding the below code to `settings.json`, because sometimes we people tell them the extension does not work if the file is `*.html.erb` instead of `*.erb`. And that tends to be rails defaults.

```
    "files.associations": {
        "*.erb": "erb"
    }
```

**So, all you need to do is replace `html` with `*` on your config and it should work**.

If that doesn't work, please try installing [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aliariff.vscode-erb-beautify).

Comment: Thanks for your help, It really helps.

Comment: Happy to help, @junjing

Comment: @svelandiag What do you mean by "break them"? Do they start being recognized as `erb` vs `JS`? have you tried doing `"*.html.erb": "erb"` ?

Comment: @lucasarruda when I apply the config the javascript is not highlighted in .js.erb files

Comment: @svelandiag when you remove does it work again? Did you try changing the config to `"*.html.erb": "erb"`?